# Store vs Store<T>

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm pretty much a novice with the `redux` pattern and have just started using `ngrx`. It's awesome and it's something I want to use as much as possible, but I have a couple of questions regarding the `Store` concept.

I will try to describe the problem through a few samples and ask my question at the end of this post.

Let's start with the `AppState` interface and reducers:

```
export interface AppState{
   people: Person[],
   events: Event[]
}

//events reducer
export function eventsReducer(state: any = {}, {type, payload}): Event[]{
  switch(type){
    case "ADD_EVENT":
      return [...state, payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//people reducer
export function peopleReducer(state: any = {}, {type, payload}): Person[]{
  switch(type){
    case "ADD_PERSON":
      return [...state, payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//root reducer
const root: ActionReducer<AppState> = combineReducers({people: peopleReducer, events: eventsReducer});
const INITIAL_STATE = {
   people:[],
   events: []
}
export function rootReducer(state: any = INITIAL_STATE, action: any){
   return root(state, action);
}
```

`rootReducer` is added like this:

```
//part of the AppModule
...
imports:[
...,
StoreModule.provideStore(rootReducer)
]
```

And in the main `AppComponent` here is how I'm accesing the `store`:

```
//part of the AppComponent
export class AppComponent{
   people: Observable<Person[]>;
   events: Observable<Event[]>;

   constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
      this.people = store.select('people');
      this.events = store.select('events');
   }
}
```

Now, everything works correctly and I really like this concept, but I've noticed that nothing changes (or breaks) if I remove one of the properties from the `AppState` interface (for example, I remove the `people` property, everything else stays the same).

So I would like to know what is the main reason for having `Store<AppState>` instead of just `Store` and what are the main advantages of using `Store<AppState>` (where it's actually made a difference against just using `Store`)? Also, is there a way to enforce at least runtime errors when AppState changes, but everything else stays the same?

The possibility of me using it wrong is very high as well, but I would still like to know answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store's [`select` method](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts#L11-L26) can be passed one or more property strings or a selector function.

When passed property strings, it behaves like [`pluck`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck). And when passed a selector function, it behaves like [`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map).

The significant difference between these is that the property path(s) passed to `pluck` cannot be type checked and `pluck` returns `Observable<any>`, so the state's type information is essentially lost.

If you use selector functions, instead, you will see TypeScript errors for missing properties, etc.

For example, this:

```ts
store.select(state => state.missing);
```

will effect an error, whereas this will not:

```ts
store.select('missing');
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have been looking into what it does with `T` in the `Store<T>` implementation, but never bothered to check the `select` method.